# Displaying an entity field type as table of some properties of each entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I need have a unidirectional One-To-Many relation between two entities.
For letting user select the relations I use entity field type:

```
$builder->add('selectedItems','entity',array(
                'class'=>'MY\ExBundle\Entity\MyRow',
                'multiple'=>true,
                'expanded'=>true,
            )
        )
```

But with this I only have a `checkbox` and its label for each entity.
I need to show each entity as a table row that its columns are some properties of the underlying entity (e.g. price, count , etc.) in addition to a `checkbox` so user can see more details about entity and check them if he want.
for example:

```
+---+-------+--------+--------------+
|   | price |  count | deliveryDate |
+---+-------+--------+--------------+
| X |  100  |    6   | 2015-01-02   |
+---+-------+--------+--------------+
|   |   70  |    5   | 2015-02-03   |
+---+-------+--------+--------------+
```

How can I do this?

Should I create a new Field Type? if so how can I access the underlying child entity?

or I need to use something like embed form collections? if so how make symfony threat it as a choice list and not newly added entries.

---

Edit:
this is the `MY\ExBundle\Entity\MyRow` entity:

```
/**
 * MyRow
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ITW\BidBundle\Entity\MyRowRepository")
 */
class MyRow
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="count", type="integer")
     */
    private $count;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deliveryDate", type="date")
     */
    private $deliveryDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

}
```

---

Edit2: 
I tried to create a field type for this purpose & this is the template I used for it:

```
{%- block tablechoice_widget -%}
    <table {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        <thead>
            <th></th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>count</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    {%- for child in form %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{- form_widget(child) -}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor -%}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{%- endblock tablechoice_widget -%}
```

But I cant access the underlying entity (`MyRow`) of childs (`checkboxes`).

Comment: Sounds like these entities are related since they have the same field names.  Is there a base entity that these are derived from?  Could you use a base entity to display the rows and only use 1 entity in the form?

Comment: You want to show some `MY\ExBundle\Entity\MyRow` properties, have I understood correctly?

Comment: @George: yes, entities are from the same class  only each row is an instance of that class

Comment: @DonCallisto: please check my edit on question

Comment: I'm still not understanding. Where are "name" and "familiy"? From what entity they come up?

Comment: @DonCallisto: those was only examples! `price` , `count` & `deliveryDate` are actual fields that I want to show in columns.

Comment: You have to specify it, otherwise people trying to help you could mess the things. BTW, I'm sure that the best solution is to write explicitly a twig template for that field (so you can't take advantage of form_widget()) method where you can access directly entity field or, if you want to write code on your own, you could write a new form type that will be displayed as you want. Is up on you!

Comment: @DonCallisto: I fixed names; yes & I tried to create a field type; but in that way my problem is Ihow can I access underlying entity of each child?

Comment: In twig, simply use the DOT (.) notation and you can access every property of the object

Comment: @DonCallisto: I know that but this gives me access to `checkbox` object & not the `MyRow` !

Comment: @4r1y4n: Ok, I will show you a solution in a moment, now I got it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In twig if you use that notation (for example)

```
{{ entity.child }}
```

but `entity` is a field of your form, you will not access to actual entity object but form representation of it (so checkbox or whatever)

If you want to access "real" object (and its child) you should use

```
{{ entity.vars.data }}
```

and for its child

```
{{ entity.vars.getChild }}
```

Of course you have to adapt names to your real code.
Good Luck!

Comment: can you please clarify more about the `child` & the `vars.data` what they mean? or what they really are in this example ?

Comment: @masseleria child is just whatever is related with your entity. In that case entity is a form field (see il question). vars.data the actual underlying object